# Drawing Lines in Autoscroll form c#

Tags: c#, winforms, gdi+

I just want to transform the points when scrolling. I already use the e.Graphics.TranslateTransform() but it only works on drawing. The point of the line wont change the offset.

```
    private void Form1_Scroll(object sender, ScrollEventArgs e)
            {
                Point scrollOffset = this.AutoScrollPosition;

                for (int lk = 0; lk < Pt1.Count; lk++)
                {
                    Pt1[lk] = new Point(Pt1[lk].X + scrollOffset.X, Pt1[lk].Y + scrollOffset.Y);
                    Pt2[lk] = new Point(Pt2[lk].X + scrollOffset.X, Pt2[lk].Y + scrollOffset.Y);
                }
                this.Invalidate();
                this.Update();
                this.Refresh();
            }
 private void Form1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
        {
            Point scrollOffset = this.AutoScrollPosition;
            e.Graphics.TranslateTransform(scrollOffset.X, scrollOffset.Y);
            e.Graphics.Clear(this.BackColor);
            e.Graphics.InterpolationMode = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.InterpolationMode.High;
            e.Graphics.SmoothingMode = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.SmoothingMode.HighQuality;
            Pen greenPen = new Pen(Color.Green,1);
            greenPen.DashPattern = new float[] { 5.0F, 5.0F, 5.0F, 5.0F };
            Pen red = new Pen(Color.Red,1);
            red.DashPattern = new float[] { 5.0F, 5.0F, 5.0F, 5.0F };
            Pen Grey = new Pen(Color.Gray,1);
            Grey.DashPattern = new float[] { 5.0F, 5.0F, 5.0F, 5.0F };
            #region "Draw Line using cursor"
            Pen SolidGreen = new Pen(Color.Green, 1);
            Pen SolidGrey = new Pen(Color.Gray, 1);
            Pen Red = new Pen(Color.Red, 1);

            for (int pl = 0; pl < Pt1j.Count; pl++)
            {

                PointF[] pointsj = new PointF[] 
                    {
                    new PointF(Pt2j[pl].X, Pt2j[pl].Y),
                    new PointF(Pt3j[pl].X , Pt3j[pl].Y),
                    new PointF(Pt4j[pl].X , Pt4j[pl].Y),
                    new PointF(Pt5j[pl].X , Pt5j[pl].Y),
                    };
                e.Graphics.DrawLine(Pens.Green, Pt1j[pl].X , Pt1j[pl].Y, Pt2j[pl].X, Pt2j[pl].Y);
                e.Graphics.DrawCurve(Pens.Green, pointsj);
                e.Graphics.DrawLine(Pens.Green, Pt5j[pl].X , Pt5j[pl].Y, Pt6j[pl].X, Pt6j[pl].Y);
            }
            for (int pl = 0; pl < Pt1DashedGray.Count; pl++)
            {
                e.Graphics.DrawLine(Grey, Pt1DashedGray[pl], Pt2DashedGray[pl]);
                PointF[] pointsdhg = new PointF[] 
                    {
                    new PointF(Pt2DashedGray[pl].X, Pt2DashedGray[pl].Y),
                    new PointF(Pt3DashedGray[pl].X, Pt3DashedGray[pl].Y),
                    new PointF(Pt4DashedGray[pl].X, Pt4DashedGray[pl].Y),
                     new PointF(Pt5DashedGray[pl].X, Pt5DashedGray[pl].Y),
                    };
                e.Graphics.DrawCurve(Grey, pointsdhg);
                e.Graphics.DrawLine(Grey, Pt5DashedGray[pl], Pt6DashedGray[pl]);
            }
            for (int pl = 0; pl < Pt1SolidGray.Count; pl++)
            {
                e.Graphics.DrawLine(SolidGrey, Pt1SolidGray[pl], Pt2SolidGray[pl]);
                PointF[] pointsdhg = new PointF[] 
                    {
                    new PointF(Pt2SolidGray[pl].X, Pt2SolidGray[pl].Y),
                    new PointF(Pt3SolidGray[pl].X, Pt3SolidGray[pl].Y),
                    new PointF(Pt4SolidGray[pl].X, Pt4SolidGray[pl].Y),
                     new PointF(Pt5SolidGray[pl].X, Pt5SolidGray[pl].Y),
                    };
                e.Graphics.DrawCurve(SolidGrey, pointsdhg);
                e.Graphics.DrawLine(SolidGrey, Pt5SolidGray[pl], Pt6SolidGray[pl]);
            }



            for (int pl = 0; pl < Pt1DashGreen.Count; pl++)
            {
                e.Graphics.DrawLine(greenPen, Pt1DashGreen[pl], Pt2DashGreen[pl]);
                PointF[] pointsdhg = new PointF[] 
                    {
                    new PointF(Pt2DashGreen[pl].X, Pt2DashGreen[pl].Y),
                    new PointF(Pt3DashGreen[pl].X, Pt3DashGreen[pl].Y),
                    new PointF(Pt4DashGreen[pl].X, Pt4DashGreen[pl].Y),
                    new PointF(Pt5DashGreen[pl].X, Pt5DashGreen[pl].Y),
                    };
                e.Graphics.DrawCurve(greenPen, pointsdhg);
                e.Graphics.DrawLine(greenPen, Pt5DashGreen[pl], Pt6DashGreen[pl]);
            }

            for (int i = 0; i < Pt1.Count; i++)
            {
                e.Graphics.DrawLine(SolidGreen, Pt1[i], Pt2[i]);
            }
            for (int l = 0; l < DashedGreen1.Count; l++)
            {
                e.Graphics.DrawLine(greenPen, DashedGreen1[l], DashedGreen2[l]);
            }

            for (int k = 0; k < SolidGrey1.Count; k++)
            {
                e.Graphics.DrawLine(SolidGrey, SolidGrey1[k], SolidGrey2[k]);
            }
            for (int j = 0; j < DashedGrey1.Count; j++)
            {
                e.Graphics.DrawLine(Grey, DashedGrey1[j], DashedGrey2[j]);
            }
                if (IsDrawing)
                {
                    e.Graphics.DrawLine(Red, NewPt1.X, NewPt1.Y, NewPt2.X, NewPt2.Y);
                }
                if (Draw_Dashed_Green)
                {
                    e.Graphics.DrawLine(red, DashedGreenPT1, DashedGreenPT2);
                }
                if (Draw_Solid_Grey)
                {
                    e.Graphics.DrawLine(Red, SolidGreyPT1, SolidGreyPT2);
                }
                if (Draw_dashed_Grey)
                {
                    e.Graphics.DrawLine(red, DashedGreyPT1, DashedGreyPT2);
                }
        }
```

Need Help
Here is my code so far.
BDW, The point of the line is stored in the list from.
The Drawn lines in Paint event also include the line jumpers which has 6 points on it to make a jumps.

So the only problem is I would like to change the Points of the lines as I use the scroll bar.
Thanks for answering my question.

Comment: Can you explain what is the effect that you looking for? Are you trying to move the lines position on the surface using the Scrollbars? Or keep them steady? The `AutoScrollPosition` reports negative values. (Btw, you just need `Invalidate()`)

Comment: Uhmmm ... I would like to move the lines position when using the scrollbar. I already use Invalidate() and I put the e.Graphics.TranslateTransform() in the paint event and it works. But the only problem is the point didnt move , only the drawn lines.

Comment: Then post the Paint event code. As it is, this is very uncleary to me what you're trying to achieve. Also because, as I said before `AutoScrollPosition` gives negative values. Then, *I already use Invalidate()*. I meant you need `Invalidate()` alone. Adding `Update()` and `Refresh()` causes a second repaint for each `Scroll()` event change.

Comment: private void Form1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
        {
            Point scrollOffset = this.AutoScrollPosition;
            e.Graphics.TranslateTransform(scrollOffset.X, scrollOffset.Y);
            e.Graphics.Clear(this.BackColor);

Comment: Nope, you need to [Edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/53219621/edit) your question, adding any code snippet or description that can further explain your case. Don't insert code in comments.

Comment: Aww I see,,, It works fine and theres no flickering by using only the Invalidate(). Now only want to make the point changes when I use the scrollbar..

Comment: A picture of the desired output would help.

Comment: At first [link](https://screenshot.net/wowdpae) and then if I scroll this will happen [link](https://screenshot.net/nnyo7fl) and I dont want that, What I want is to move the Line As I scroll just like the pictureboxes